# Python curve fit multiple variable

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, model-fitting

I am trying to fit a function with multiple variables, my fit_function returns  two values, and I need to find best parameters that fit for both values.

Here is the sample code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Fit function returns two values
def func(X, a, b, c):
    x,y = X
    val1 = np.log(a) + b*np.log(x) + c*np.log(y)
    val2 = np.log(a)-4*val1/3
    return (val1,val2)

# some artificially noisy data to fit
x = np.linspace(0.1,1.1,101)
y = np.linspace(1.,2., 101)
a, b, c = 10., 4., 6.
z ,v = func((x,y), a, b, c) * 1 + np.random.random(101) / 100

# initial guesses for a,b,c:
p0 = 8., 2., 7.
   
curve_fit(func, (x,y), (z,v), p0)
```

It works fine with fitfunction of one return value, but it is not working with two. It gives : N=3 must not exceed M=2 error.

```
if n > m:
     raise TypeError('Improper input: N=%s must not exceed M=%s' % (n, m))    
Improper input: N=3 must not exceed M=2
```

I need to find parameters that minimize the residual between `val1 - z` and `val2- v` at the same time.

What I am missing here ?

This is how my input data looks like.

[image: Graphs]

I need parameters that fits both z/x and v/x.

Comment: By definition, given one `x` value, a function should return one `y` value.  You seem to be returning two `y` values, I'm not sure what you are solving.  If you were to write out the equation to the fit function by hand, what would it look like?

Comment: I add the pictures

Comment: I don't think you can get the same *parameters* to fit both curves since they are not the same curves.  The left looks like it's monotonically increasing, while the right trend appears flat.  As far as I know, you can only fit one line at a time.   Now if you want one *model* that fits both (log vs. sin vs. linear), then consider scikit learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As observed by others, your function needs to return something with the shape of the input data, so you would need to change the output shape of your error function. Since `scipy` does a least squares function, this is achieved by making your function return `np.sqrt(val1 ** 2 + val2 ** 2)`.

However, for this type of problem I prefer to use a wrapper around `scipy` which I wrote, to streamline this process of dealing with multiple components, called [`symfit`](https://symfit.readthedocs.io/).

In `symfit`, this example problem would solved as follows:

```
from symfit import parameters, variables, log, Fit, Model
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y, z1, z2 = variables('x, y, z1, z2')
a, b, c = parameters('a, b, c')

z1_component = log(a) + b * log(x) + c * log(y)
model_dict = {
    z1: z1_component,
    z2: log(a) - 4 * z1_component/3
}
model = Model(model_dict)
print(model)

# Make example data
xdata = np.linspace(0.1, 1.1, 101)
ydata = np.linspace(1.0, 2.0, 101)
z1data, z2data = model(x=xdata, y=ydata, a=10., b=4., c=6.) + np.random.random(101)

# Define a Fit object for this model and data. Demand a > 0.
a.min = 0.0
fit = Fit(model_dict, x=xdata, y=ydata, z1=z1data, z2=z2data)
fit_result = fit.execute()
print(fit_result)

# Make a plot of the result
plt.scatter(xdata, z1data, s=1, color='blue')
plt.scatter(xdata, z2data, s=1, color='green')
plt.plot(xdata, model(x=xdata, y=ydata, **fit_result.params).z1, color='blue')
plt.plot(xdata, model(x=xdata, y=ydata, **fit_result.params).z2, color='green')
```

Output:

```
z1(x, y; a, b, c) = b*log(x) + c*log(y) + log(a)
z2(x, y; a, b, c) = -4*b*log(x)/3 - 4*c*log(y)/3 - log(a)/3

Parameter Value        Standard Deviation
a         2.859766e+01 1.274881e+00
b         4.322182e+00 2.252947e-02
c         5.008192e+00 5.497656e-02
Fitting status message: b'CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH'
Number of iterations:   23
Regression Coefficient: 0.9961974241602712
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

scipy.optimize.curve_fit is checking to see if you have at least as many data points as fitted parameters by comparing the length of func's parameter list (a,b,c) as 3 with the length of the dependent variable (z,v) as 2. Yes, both z and v have more than three data points, but the length of (z,v) is two.